# Simba ODBC driver (130) Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, odbc

When I trying to connect to BigQuery with Simba ODBC driver using service authentication, I have error

> (130) Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery.

But only on Windows Server 2012 R2. For development I using Windows 7 and same settings work just fine. Also user authentication on server side works as well. I tried reinstall ODBC drivers. So I wondering if those drivers just does not have support for Windows Server 2012 R2 or there is some other issue. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: As suggested on the [support page for that driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support), you might want to move this question to stackoverflow - I've the correct tag to your question

Comment: Ok, I did want at first put it there, but then realized that it is not about programming, I think its against the rules to put not coding retailed question.